# How to take multiple integers into a single register, from a keyboard input (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am working on a project, and seeing this issue where I'm needing to take multiple integers from a single input/register.

For example, I'm needing to create two inputs, to store something like:

"Enter Input:"

1 2 3 4 5 6

(Stores into list, or something like 'array: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6')

To store this in a single register to be sorted, then merged.

I already have the sort portion figured out, but once the input is solved, the rest should be fine.

Comment: A register only holds 4 bytes, not strings or arrays.  Do you want to hold a *pointer* to an array, like as a function arg?  Like a C function `void sort(int *arr, int len)`, which takes args in `$a0` and `$a1` in the standard MIPS calling convention?  Or do you want to actually pack the data into 4-bit-per-digit BCD or binary bitfields, so you can fit 8 numbers, each 0..15, into one register?  You'd have to unpack them again to compare them, though, so that's not normally useful.

Comment: Can you work out an algorithm in C or any other language?